# Moving through datagridview rows on keypress

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to go through datagridview rows where the cell value starts with the same keychar the user pressed. Code bellow works, but It wont move selection to next row starting with same letter when I press same letter second, third time...

```
     Private Sub dataGridView1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dgw.KeyPress
    If [Char].IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To (dgw.Rows.Count) - 1
            If dgw.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString().StartsWith(e.KeyChar.ToString(), True, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) Then
                If lastKey = e.KeyChar And lastIndex < i Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                lastKey = e.KeyChar
                lastIndex = i
                dgw.Rows(i).Cells(1).Selected = True
                Return

            End If

        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've updated my code but still it wont loop through all rows starting with same letter.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a flaw in the logic. You press key, save index and break. Then you press the same key. And if lastIndex is lesser than i you continue. Which means it will only select the first row it finds with a lesser value than the last one. Change to lastindex > i and you should be fine.

You can with the code you have written never get anything else than the first line matching the key. After that it doesn't matter how many times you press.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is too old this post... anyway I've found a workaround for this and maybe it will be useful for someone.

```
public lastkey as string


    Private Sub dataGridView1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dgw.KeyPress

                            Dim input = StrConv(e.keychar.toString()
                            lastkey += input
                            Dim found as Boolean    


                      if StrConv(dgw.currentCell.Value.toString.Substring(0,1), VbStrConv.UpperCase) = input then
                            dim curIndex = dgw.currentRow.Index
                            if curIndex < dgw.rows.count - 1 then
                                dgw.ClearSelection()
                                curIndex += 1
                                dgw.currentCell = dgw.rows(curIndex).Cells(0)
                                dgw.rows(curIndex).selected = true
                            end if
                     else
                            dgv_jumpRecord(lastkey,found)

                            if not found then
                               lastkey = input
                               dgv_jumpRecord(lastkey,found)
                            end if   
                     End if         

   End Sub

    Public Sub dgv_jumpRecord(byVal lastkey as String, ByRef found as boolean)

                            For i As Integer = 0 To (dgw.Rows.Count) - 1

                            dim rowText = dgw.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString

                            If StrConv(rowText.ToString(),VbStrConv.UpperCase).StartsWith(lastkey) Then
                               dgw.ClearSelection()
                               dgw.CurrentCell = dgw.rows(i).Cells(0)
                               dgw.rows(i).selected = true
                               found = true
                               Exit Sub
                            End If

                            Next
                   found = false

 End Sub
```